# My social media Icons aren't working when you click on them, even though they links

Tags: javascript, html, css

i'm trying to get clickable icons and they work but when I added some stuff they stopped working. When I click on them they do not do anything like they used too

I've tried switching up the CSS and HTML and rearranging it as well as removing some CSS but the icons still wont work when clicked.

HTML

```
    <div id="star" class="video mask overlay"><canvas class="cover"></canvas></div>
    <section id="home" class="home">



    <script src="zzz/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="zzz/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="zzz/js/modernizr.custom.js"></script>
    <script src="zzz/js/plugins.min.js"></script>
    <script src="zzz/js/main.js"></script>

</head>
 <body scroll="no" style="overflow: hidden">
<body>
<div class="textglitch">
  <a class="textglitch-link"><span>Elf</span></a>
</div>
  <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script  src="function.js"></script>
    <div class="gg">
    <a href="https://www.byron-bay.com/" target="_blank">
<img src="twitter.png" alt="aim" class="gg">
<a href="https://www.byron-bay.com/" target="_blank">
<img src="twitter.png" alt="aim" class="gg">
<a href="https://www.byron-bay.com/" target="_blank">
<img src="twitter.png" alt="aim" class="gg">
<a href="https://www.byron-bay.com/" target="_blank">
<img src="twitter.png" alt="aim" class="gg">
<a href="https://www.byron-bay.com/" target="_blank">
<img src="twitter.png" alt="aim" class="gg">
<a href="https://www.byron-bay.com/" target="_blank">
<img src="twitter.png" alt="aim" class="gg">
<a href="https://www.byron-bay.com/" target="_blank">
<img src="twitter.png" alt="aim" class="gg">
<a href="https://www.byron-bay.com/" target="_blank">
<img src="twitter.png" alt="aim" class="gg">
<div>
</a>
</body>
```

CSS

```
* {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  outline:none;
  list-style:none;
  text-decoration:none;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  color:#000;
  background: transparent;
  border:none;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;  
    margin-top: 10%;
}

body {
  background: #111;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.textglitch {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 1;
  font-size: 5vw;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin: 50px 0;
}

.textglitch .textglitch-link {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.textglitch-link span {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  color: #fff;
}

.blur {
  filter: blur(1px);
  -webkit-filter: blur(1px);
}

.textglitch .textglitch-link:after,
.textglitch .textglitch-link:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  content: attr(data-content);
  visibility: hidden;
}

.textglitch.active .textglitch-link:after,
.textglitch.active .textglitch-link:before {
  visibility: visible;
}

.textglitch .textglitch-link:before {
  color: rgba(255, 0, 188, 0.8);
  -webkit-animation: textglitch .3s cubic-bezier(.25, .46, .45, .94) both infinite;
  animation: textglitch .3s cubic-bezier(.25, .46, .45, .94) both infinite;
}


.textglitch .textglitch-link:after {
  color: rgba(0,255,255,0.8);
  -webkit-animation: textglitch .3s cubic-bezier(.25, .46, .45, .94) reverse both infinite;
  animation: textglitch .3s cubic-bezier(.25, .46, .45, .94) reverse both infinite;
}

@keyframes textglitch {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0);
    transform: translate(0)
  }
  20% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-3px, 3px);
    transform: translate(-3px, 3px)
  }
  40% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-3px, -3px);
    transform: translate(-3px, -3px)
  }
  60% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(3px, 3px);
    transform: translate(3px, 3px)
  }
  80% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(3px, -3px);
    transform: translate(3px, -3px)
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0);
    transform: translate(0)
  }
}
.gg {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
 text-align: center;
}
div.gg {
margin: 0 auto;
width: 120em;
}

.cover{
    background:none !important;
}
.cover,
.image,
.video,


.video-fallback {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

I wanted it to be when I clicked it it would open a new tab and go to the page.

[The](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ujvpb.png)  added

I've added the  But it is still unclickable.

[doesn't work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/39p15.png)

Comment: You have 8 opening `<a>` tags and one closing `</a>` tag

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this:

`<a href="link"><img src="source"/></a>`

Basically you need to enclose the image within the  tags!